# AWS API gateway backend API authentication

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-application-load-balancer

Is it possible to authenticate with AWS Signature V4, and set access policies to backend  API's based on the identity associated to the signature?

Or are signed messages only used for accessing AWS Infrastructure API's.  e.g. The API Gateway API's and not the API's it is managing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. If you set the `authorizationType` on a method defined in API Gateway to `AWS_IAM` then the method can only be invoked if the request is signed by an AWS principal (a user or an assumed role) which is allowed to perform the `execute-api:Invoke` action on that method.

See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-control-access-using-iam-policies-to-invoke-api.html for details on how to specify the actions. In short, your policy should allow `execute-api:Invoke` for an ARN or ARNs with the format:

```
arn:aws:execute-api:region:account-id:api-id/stage-name/HTTP-VERB/resource-path-specifier
```

By assigning different policies to different principals each principal can have a different level of access. For instance you could have a policy which allowed all HTTP-VERBs which is a read-write level of access, and another which only allowed GET, HEAD and OPTIONS as a read-only level of access to the API. Or you could use different resource-path-specifiers to only allow certain resource paths for each principal.